# AngularJS: ng-class not working with boolean function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-directive

I'm trying to accomplish this: Change button icon and color class if list element is present on an array. If the object is not present, the icon will be a `glyphicon-plus` with `btn-success` Bootstrap class. Otherwise, there will be a `glyphicon-minus` with `btn-danger` class. The `isSelected` function returns a boolean value indicating the presence or the absence of the object inside the list. However, every time I open my modal (Angular-UI-Bootstrap), there is a parse error from `isSelected`.

How to proper set a boolean function within `ng-class` directive?

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="ex in exams track by ex.uid" ng-class="{selected: ex.uid === selectedExam.uid}" ng-click="rowclick(ex)" ng-dblclick="pushToRemoveFromSelectedList(ex)">
        <td>{{ ex.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ ex.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ ex.code }}</td>
        <td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{ ex.class }}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ng-class="'btn btn-sm btn-success':!isSelected(ex), 'btn btn-sm btn-danger':isSelected(ex)" ng-click="pushToRemoveFromSelectedList(ex)">
                <span ng-class="'glyphicon glyphicon-plus':!isSelected(ex), 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus':isSelected(ex)"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If you still plan on using the object map to apply the classes, you'll have to use `{ 'class': expr }`.  You left off the `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as how you wrapped your `tr` element's `ng-class` with `{}`, you also need to do it with the `ng-class` attribute for both the `button` and `span` elements.

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-sm"
  ng-class="{'btn-success': !isSelected(ex), 'btn-danger': isSelected(ex)}"
  ng-click="pushToRemoveFromSelectedList(ex)">

  <span class="glyphicon"
    ng-class="{'glyphicon-plus': !isSelected(ex), 'glyphicon-minus': isSelected(ex)}">
  </span>

</button>
```

Alternatively, you can choose to use a ternary operator to toggle between two classes.

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-sm"
  ng-class="isSelected(ex)? 'btn-danger': 'btn-success'"
  ng-click="pushToRemoveFromSelectedList(ex)">

  <span class="glyphicon"
    ng-class="isSelected(ex)? 'glyphicon-minus': 'glyphicon-plus'">
  </span>

</button>
```

An advantage in this alternative is that it only needs to invoke `isSelected(ex)` twice per `ng-repeat` item while the first one would trigger four invocations.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to wrap your attribute value in `{}`.

Try this:

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-sm"
        ng-class="'{ btn-success':!isSelected(ex), 'btn-danger':isSelected(ex) }"
        ng-click="pushToRemoveFromSelectedList(ex)">
    <span class="glyphicon"
          ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-plus':!isSelected(ex), 'glyphicon-minus':isSelected(ex) }"></span>
</button>
```

I separated out `class="btn btn-sm"`, since those classes are used in both cases.

Comment: you forgot to do the same on the spans ng-class